# How to install an extension in Firefox-ESR?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, firefox-addon, ubuntu-23.10

I created a simple extension and it is working when I am loading it manually via `about:debugging`. However, I'd like this extension to start automatically without having to load it manually. 
Following the [Deploying Firefox with extensions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/deploying-firefox-with-extensions) guide:

> Step 1: Create directories In the Firefox ESR installation directory,
> you will need create some required directories. First, create a
> directory called distribution. Inside of that directory, create
> another called extensions.

---

> Step 2: Add extensions We now need to add our extensions into the
> extensions directory that we created above. This will require you to
> know the add-on ID for each extension that you wish to add to this
> directory.
>
> To add the extensions to this directory, you should include the
> extension's XPI file. It will need to be renamed to the add-on ID,
> while being careful to keep the .xpi file extension.

In `manifest.json` I created an add-on ID as follows:

```
"browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "tony@myext"
    }
}
```

And I copied the `tony@myext.xpi` to `/usr/lib/firefox-esr/distribution/extensions`. I closed Firefox and restarted it and the extension was not working (it is supposed to block access to a specific url which works when I load the extension manually).

Any ideas will be appreciated as the internet is somewhat sparse with terrible documentation...